# 手臂 vs 胳膊 difference

Tags: meaning, difference

I know that both words mean "arm", but is there any real difference between 手臂 and 胳膊? When I started to learn Mandarin at university, they taught me to use 手臂, but now I see that 胳膊 is the one included on the HSK4 vocabulary list.

Is there any difference regarding the "part" of the arm that they represent? Is it a matter of one being more formal than the other?

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

"手臂" = "arm" -- Includes "上臂" (upper arm) and "前臂" (forearm)

[胳](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%83%B3) = armpit; [胳](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2947/) = arm

[膊](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2971/) = upper arm

"[胳膊](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/11927/)" (upper arm region) --> "**arm**" -- Includes "上臂" (upper arm) and "前臂" (forearm)

"肩頭" = shoulder

"肩膊" = shoulder/ shoulder region

**Both "手臂" and "胳膊" mean "arm"**

**"手臂" is more colloquial and "胳膊" is more literary.**

Comment: 胳膊 is more colloquial in my neck of woods. 手臂 is more a technical term instead.

Answer (score 2):

手臂 includes hands and arms. 胳膊 is the arms only.

Comment: 手臂 doesn't include hand just like 腳脛 doesn't include foot; 眼皮 doesn't include eye and 頭髮 doesn't include the head. 在手臂上打針 never include the option of injecting in the hand

Comment: 手臂 = 手  and 臂, but 眼皮 = 眼's 皮 ， 头发 = 头's 发. These are not comparable

Comment: @Tang Ho 洪深《电影戏剧表演术》第三章五：“手臂自然地分为三段：上臂、前臂与手。” If it means different things in Cantonese, please notify. I guess so because 腳脛 is not a common word.

Comment: 肩連上臂，上臂連前臂，前臂連手掌, 手掌連手指. (手臂指上臂及前臂)

Comment: 如說 "切下手臂"，因為手是連接在手臂上的, 所以一條斷臂也包括了手部，但如說"在手臂上打針"，指的就只是上下臂，並不包括手部